# A simple routing rule is not working in Symfony4

Tags: php, routes, symfony4

I'm trying to create a simple routing rule in Symfony4 using Apache as webserver, but it is not working properly.

I can see the main / rule, but not anyone.

I've installed my project following these commands:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton s4-02-routing 
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

It's my **routes.yaml** file...

```
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

And this it's the controller...

```
<?php

// src/Controller/LuckyController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController {

    public function number() {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
                '<html><body>Lucky number: ' . $number . '</body></html>'
        );
    }

}
```

The **.htaccess** file exists, and this is the virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            AllowOverride All
#           Order Allow,Deny
            Require all granted
            Allow from All
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

The main URL **http://192.168.2.12/s4-02-routing/public/** is working properly since I can see:

> Welcome to Symfony 4.3.2 Your application is now ready. You can start
>   working on it at: /var/www/html/s4-02-routing/

But, the URL **http://192.168.2.12/s4-02-routing/public/lucky/number** is not working, because I see a symfony error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. (2/2)
>   NotFoundHttpException No route found for "GET /lucky/number"

But, the rule is well created:

```
vagrant@06f2a172f274:/var/www/html/s4-02-routing$ php bin/console debug:router
 ------------------ -------- -------- ------ ---------------
  Name               Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 ------------------ -------- -------- ------ ---------------
  index              ANY      ANY      ANY    /
  app_lucky_number   ANY      ANY      ANY    /lucky/number
```

What is wrong? Thanks your any help.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer. I installed the apache-pack, when I go to http://192.168.2.12/s4-02-routing/public/index.php/lucky/number it's automatically changed to http://192.168.2.12/s4-02-routing/public/lucky/number

Comment: Don't edit "(Solved)" into the question title. Add a new answer and accept it when you can; this is the proper way to close a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to solve the issue: cleaning the cache...

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```